# PlanningVariable within a PlanningVariable

Tags: optaplanner

When creating a schedule you have to abide by the law (hard requirement) that stipulates
that as an employee you are only allowed to work a certain amount of hours per each given **Sevenday** period. The reason that it does not say calendar week is to provide some wiggle room for the employer when creating the schedule (usually for 4-16 weeks ahead). Once your `startdate` for this planning period is set it cannot change until you want to do a complete replanning but then you need to inform your employees.
So it can be seen as a variable until you have accepted the schedule then it becomes a constant. It is individual for each employee of course. This `startdate` would be implicitly set by your first assigned shift's start date ofc but
it usually not enough to finetune the schedule.

So assume we want to create a fresh schedule for the first 3 calendar months of the year for Alice and Bob they will each be assigned a `startdate` that may or may not be the same date as the first assigned shift (cant be after ofc :)).

So basically once Optaplanner has assigned a `startdate` to the employee it should try to make the best schedule out of that but simultaneously have the freedom to update the `startdate` to create an even better schedule and for next planningperiod this should no longer be decalared as a planningvariable. Can you setup that aswell without changeing the code?

My question is how I declare this StartDate variable in the Employee model? It is a pure planning variable within the planning variable as you can see below in the models.
Or is it classified as an AnchorVariable? How do I declare the value range as {20200101 - 20203030}? It can be down to hours and minutes but not seconds and milliseconds.

I read up on the Chained Variables but my Entities (Shift Assignments) itself are not chained or dependent on each other like in the TSP problem.

```
public Employee {
   String name
   
   Date startDate <-- PlanningVariable?, AnchorVariable? how to declare the valuerange?
}

public Shift {
    Date start
    
    Date end
}

@PlanningEntity
public ShiftAssignment {
    Shift shift
    
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"employeeRange"})   <--Employee is a planningvariable here
    Employee employee
}

@PlanningSolution
public ShiftRooster {
   
   @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
   private List<Employee> employees
   
   @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
   private List<ShiftAssignment> shiftAssignments
}
```

Do I need to wrap the `startDate` in Employee in a Class to able to annotate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Business wise, I would find it strange that the employee's "sevenday weekday start" isn't an input to the planning problem. Because either:

- you hit the ground running: they already have a schedule and you need to nit onto it at the end. For example, given a 4 week publishing notice, the have a schedule until 28 Feb (done manually or by legacy software) and before 1 Feb you need to add a schedule starting on 1 March. You have zero choice about their "sevenday weekday start".
- You have the opportunity to do a disruptive reset of their "sevenday weekday start" of all employees, alongside introducing a totally new planning system (*good luck!*). Given a planning window of maybe 2-3 months, you 're going to make decisions for a time period that don't involve Christmas and/or summer break, events which will likely put stress on those sevenday related constraints.

In a first phase, I'd leave it out of scope to optimize that start, take it as in input parameter, using the values they have been using all along. And in a second phase, I'd run simulations for a planning window of 1 year, in case a new employee joins and you want to automatically decided the "sevenday weekday start".

Also, if an employee's first shift starts on 4-Feb, it can still be optimal to start his/her "sevenday weekday start" on 2-Feb, for example if the week of 20-Feb is the moment that half the employees are on PTO, and having his/her sevenday reset on 23-Feb would be ideal.

Comment: You are right about coming from a legacy system (manually in this case) those date have been already been set. For clarification, it is set down to hours and minutes not only date. So your first shift can be 20-feb 08:00 but your "sevenday period" is set at 19-feb 07:30 giving you an initial rest of 24,5 hours. So one path is to investigate what optimization can be done using the already set startdate, the other path is as you stated "Start fresh".

Comment: At this point in the project, it is more investigating the potential creating schedules with this kind of software and I would like to see what further optimization can be done with if you can change the startdate. It does not involve many employees and I think that if you can alleviate the biggest criticism from the employees a complete reset can be planned for (after summer vacation possibly). There could still be a benefit in the existing workplace when you want to create a temporary schedule for summer workers if you do not want them to mirror the existing schedule. Also, I want learn:)

Comment: Makes sense :) And for the record, it can be optimized too with OptaPlanner - a separate SO answer should try to actually solve the question as originally desired - but it introduces a good deal of complexity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968605/employee-schedule-with-individual-and-vairiable-startdate-for-each-employee